# getting null values when trying to pass values to xml response in web service from model class

Tags: java

```
/**
 * ConnectDB2.java , i'm fetching data from database and setting values to model class.
 */
  package org.com.repair.spotify.repair.db;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.ws.rs.Path;

import org.com.repair.spotify.repair.model.RepairDetails;

/**
 * @author www.javaworkspace.com
 * 
 */
@Path("/connectDB2")
public class ConnectDB2 {
    Connection connection = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    String deviceName;
    String deviceModel;
    String ticketId;
    String issue;
    String deviceType;

    public ConnectDB2() {
        try {

            Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/HELLO", "db2admin", "admin");
            statement = connection.createStatement();

            resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM DEVICE ");
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                System.out.println("DEVICE BRAND:" + resultSet.getString(1)
                        + " || ISSUE: " + resultSet.getString(2) + " ||MODEL:"
                        + resultSet.getString(3) + "||TYPE:"
                        + resultSet.getString(4));
                RepairDetails Rd = new RepairDetails();
                Rd.setDeviceModel(resultSet.getString(1));
                Rd.setIssue(resultSet.getString(2));
                Rd.setDeviceType(resultSet.getString(3));
                Rd.setDeviceType(resultSet.getString(4));

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                resultSet.close();
                statement.close();
                connection.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

/*RepairDetails.java==> my Model class*/

```
package org.com.repair.spotify.repair.model;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
@XmlRootElement
public class RepairDetails {

    String deviceName;
    String deviceModel;
    String ticketId;
    String issue;
    String deviceType;

    public RepairDetails() {

    }

    public RepairDetails(String deviceName, String deviceModel,
            String ticketId, String issue, String deviceType) {
        super();
        this.deviceName = deviceName;
        this.deviceModel = deviceModel;
        this.ticketId = ticketId;
        this.issue = issue;
        this.deviceType = deviceType;
    }

    public String getDeviceName() {
        System.out.println("getter" + deviceName);
        return deviceName;
    }

    public void setDeviceName(String deviceName) {
        System.out.println("setter" + deviceName);
        this.deviceName = deviceName;
    }

    public String getDeviceModel() {
        return deviceModel;
    }

    public void setDeviceModel(String deviceModel) {
        System.out.println("setter" + deviceModel);
        this.deviceModel = deviceModel;
    }

    public String getTicketId() {
        return ticketId;
    }

    public void setTicketId(String ticketId) {
        this.ticketId = ticketId;
    }

    public String getIssue() {
        return issue;
    }

    public void setIssue(String issue) {
        System.out.println("setter" + issue);
        this.issue = issue;
    }

    public String getDeviceType() {
        return deviceType;
    }

    public void setDeviceType(String deviceType) {
        System.out.println("setter" + deviceType);
        this.deviceType = deviceType;
    }

}
```

//the service class from where i'm trying get values from model, but i'm fetching null value which is further passed on getRepairdetails()

```
package org.com.repair.spotify.repair.service;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.com.repair.spotify.repair.db.ConnectDB2;
import org.com.repair.spotify.repair.model.*;

public class RepairService {

    public RepairService() {
        ConnectDB2 db = new ConnectDB2();
    }

    public List<RepairDetails> getRepairService()

    {
        System.out.println("getRepairDetails-->2");
        RepairDetails Rd = new RepairDetails();

        System.out.println("hey im firing");
        RepairDetails RD1 = new RepairDetails(Rd.getDeviceName(),
                Rd.getDeviceModel(), Rd.getIssue(), Rd.getDeviceType(),
                "Mobile");
        List<RepairDetails> list = new ArrayList<RepairDetails>();
        list.add(RD1);
        return list;

    }

}
```

Kindly help me why null values are returned by getter ???

Comment: I would suggest **Stepping** through the code with your IDE Debugger. I'm sure it will quickly divulge the reason why.

Comment: Add a break-point at the last of the function that is returning null, and then you will be able to watch the stack trace. Move it up a bit and then you'll be finding your error.

Comment: @DevilsHnd Thank you for responding.yeah even while debugging setter is setting the values , whereas i'm surprised why getter is returning null values :(

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with examining the `RepairDetails` class. This one implements a **POJO** (Plain old Java object) and contains two constructors.

- `public RepairDetails()`
- `public RepairDetails(String, String, String, String, String)`

So when you create the object with the first constructor, that means you are not setting anything to the fields, that means that the values are initialized to `null`.

Now let's examine the `RepairService` class. There you have this code in the `getRepairService()` method.

```
RepairDetails Rd = new RepairDetails();

RepairDetails RD1 = new RepairDetails(Rd.getDeviceName(),
        Rd.getDeviceModel(), Rd.getIssue(), Rd.getDeviceType(),
        "Mobile");

List<RepairDetails> list = new ArrayList<RepairDetails>();
list.add(RD1);
```

Here we have the following observations:

- `Rd` is an object created with the first constructor, so effectively the values in `Rd` will be `null`.
- You are constructing `RD1` with values got from `Rd` meaning that they will be `null` too.

I hope you get it now.

Comment: i got your point. But how to call the values(getter()) of POJO class attributes for which i'm setting values fetched from database and send them to the constructor and display in output response(XML).                              Current Output : from the following constructor call RepairDetails RD1 = new RepairDetails(Rd.getDeviceName(),
        Rd.getDeviceModel(), Rd.getIssue(), Rd.getDeviceType(),
        "Mobile");  only the hard coded "mobile" value is displayed whereas rest of arguments are passed as null

Comment: Current Output: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="true"?>
-<repairDetailss><repairDetails><deviceType>Mobile</deviceType></repairDetails></repairDetailss>